# How to use Disconnect when sending bulk emails with Mailkit?

Tags: c#, mailkit

I need to send emails in bulk (each email is different in body and attachments) and I'm doing something like this:

```
if (client == null) {
    client.Connect(...);
    client.Authenticate(...);
}

foreach (var message in list) {
   client.Send(message);
   client.Disconnect(false);
}

client.Disconnect(true);
```

Is this best practice on how to disconnect when sending bulk emails? Is it necessary to call `Disconnect(false)` if the client is still connected?

Comment: I've not used it in this way, so this is just what sounds reasonable to me, but do you actually have to disconnect between calls to `Send`? Is it not possible to just call Send for all of your messages and then disconnect afterwards?

Comment: The SMTP class in Net requires a disconnect between sending emails.  If you are sending bulk emails use BCC so one user doesn't see other users email address.

Comment: You don't need to disconnect after each Send(). In fact, the sample code usage would never work because the code doesn't reconnect each time through the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother disconnecting after each Send().

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
    client.Connect (host, port, sslOptions);
    client.Authenticate (username, password);

    foreach (var message in messages)
        client.Send (message);

    client.Disconnect (true);
}
```